# Dynamically create one or more borders around image

Tags: javascript, css

Need to have an unknown number of borders around an image, already made a solution, just want to know whether there are better possibilities.

I have a website with many photo shows. Each show is a JSON file in which each photo is an array entry in that file, e.g.

```
{
"filename": "02.jpg", 
"short": "text under thumbnail",
"title": "A description or explanation above the photo"
}
```

Normally the photos get a small white border, but sometimes I want to show the location of that photo so in the JSON file I have this additional info for that photo:

```
"latitude": "51 02 39.73 N",
"longitude": "114 03 47.37 W",
```

I put a yellow border around the photo as indication that there is location info, so a click on the photo or one of the coordinates (or keyboard M) opens googleMaps to show the location.

Recently I added some videos to some of the photos, so double click the photo (or keyboard V) to start that video. I put a turquoise border around the photo to indicate that there is a video.
In the JSON file it looks like this:

```
"video": "myvideo.mp4",
```

Of course all of a sudden I had a photo with location info AND a video, so now I needed 2 borders: a yellow one and a turquoise one...
To complicate matters, I once in a while have a photo with a soundclip and a green border, defined in the JSON file as:

```
"sound": "myclip.mp3",
```

thus a photo with 3 different colored borders could also happen.

After reading some stackoverflow box-shadow articles, I came up with the following solution in Javascript to create 1,2,3 or even more borders:

```
var borderStyle = "";
if (elt.longitude) {
  borderStyle = "coordbrdr";
}
if (elt.sound) {
  borderStyle += "soundbrdr";
}
if (elt.video) {
  borderStyle += "videobrdr";
}   
if (borderStyle == "") {borderStyle = "normalbrdr";}
$(elt.imgHTML).attr('class', borderStyle);
```

and the accompanying css:

```
.normalbrdr {border:6px solid white;} 
.coordbrdr {border:6px solid yellow; cursor:pointer;} 
.soundbrdr {border:6px solid lightgreen; cursor:pointer;}
.videobrdr {border:6px solid turquoise; cursor:pointer;}
.coordbrdrsoundbrdr {box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px yellow, 0 0 0 12px green; cursor:pointer}
.coordbrdrvideobrdr {box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px yellow, 0 0 0 12px turquoise; cursor:pointer}
.coordbrdrsoundbrdrvideobrdr {box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px yellow, 0 0 0 12px green, 0 0 0 18px turquoise; cursor:pointer}
.soundbrdrvideobrdr {box-shadow: 0 0 0 6px green, 0 0 0 12px turquoise; cursor:pointer}
```

So in this way I managed to build the various class values.

My question: Would there be a shorter, or better method to dynamically   create different borders ??

Comment: UX advice - instead of adding multiple borders - add colored tags at the bottom

Comment: UX advice, thanks for your feedback, and of course tags at the bottom would work as well, but that would mean a different GUI, and I don't want to change the GUI. Besides, the multiple borders do work, so no need to change that. I was only wondering whether there would be a better method to GENERATE those borders than I have done in the code above, so that's why I asked the stackoveflow experts.